# One to Many lookup field in Form

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps

I've been playing around with Microsoft's PowerApps these days and I tried to develop a very small POC which is this:

- I created a "Party" entity
- And a "PartyMember" entity

Obviously a Party has a name, date and a list of PartyMembers.

How to define the List of PartyMembers is where I'm getting confused/stuck.
If I create a "PartyMember" lookup field, inside my "Party" table, it is created as a Many-to-one relationship, which does not match my needs here.

If I create a Many-to-many relationship manually, I just don't understand how to associate this relationship with a field in my entity.

Some resources I found seem to indicate that many-to-many lookup fields are just not possible right now. In that case, what's the purpose of many-to-many relationships inside the platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is three entities - Party, Member & PartyMember. **PartyMember** should have two lookups from Party & Member - this is intersect table. This is called Manual N:N (many to many) relationship. So primary key of Party & Member tables will be stored in PartyMember.

If you create a Native N:N relationship, there will be a hidden intersect entity where the association of Part & Member happens.

Or even simply create a lookup of Party in PartyMember. This way multiple members can be added to the Party. May be you added the lookup in wrong place. In 1:N relationship - `N` side (PartyMember) will have a lookup of `1` side entity (Party).

You will need a subgrid of PartyMembers in Party record.

[image]

What is impossible is creating a multi-record type lookup. That's not what you want.

Comment: Ok I understand what you're saying and what I'm doing wrong. Now let's say I created the Manual N:N relationship. If I want to create a "New Party" form, which let's me select what PartyMembers I want for this new Party, how am I supposed to include this new Entity in my form ? Is it going to show up in the "Edit Fields" sub menu, if I connect my Form to the Party Entity ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into that !